# IBM APIConnect : single quote string is not working

Tags: single-quotes, apiconnect

In **IBM API Connect**, trying to **set single quoted string value as: 'ACTIVE'**, but when i try to set completely QueryString value coming as null. 
If i remove single quoted string('ACTIVE') working fine.
Please let me know how to fix below code :

```
     action:
     - set: body.Envelope.Body.QueryString
                from:
                  - FName
                  - LName
                  - email
                value: "'select id from emp where emp.firstname ='+$(FName)+' and emp.lastname ='+$(LName)+' and primaryemail ='+$(email)+' and active =’ACTIVE’ '"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Setvariable the above issue fixed.

In Assembly ->before input, drag setVariable

In setVariable :

1. Action:set
2. set: queryString
3. value: `select id from constituent where consname.firstname='$(request.parameters.FirstName)' and consname.lastname ='$(request.parameters.LastName)' and primaryemail ='$(request.parameters.email)' and active = 'ACTIVE'`

After value, queryString mapped to input.

Now query is coming as expected as below:

```
select id from constituent where consname.firstname='Sunny' and consname.lastname ='Tom' and primaryemail ='synny.tom@gmail.com' and active = 'ACTIVE'
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather make a comment but I don't have enough reputation on the site. So, at first glance, I want to ask: Have you tried **replacing the following**:

```
’’
```

*U+2019 : RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK {single comma quotation mark}*

that are surrounding *ACTIVE* word, **for the classic symbol**:

```
''
```

*U+0027 : APOSTROPHE {APL quote}*

like all your other variable values has?